# web view content flickering in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using [this](https://github.com/fry15/uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools) lib for horizontal swipe. Check the below code

Swipe functionality works fine but when i'm going direct to slide then doesn't show content on web view.
Shown some below pic for more detail:-

[image]

After above pic when ever i'm swipe it works nice but when we want to going directly into next slide then facing content disappear problem shown below :-

[image]

and then it shows below

[image]

**code**

```
PageControl mPageControl = (PageControl) findViewById(R.id.page_control);
    mSwipeView = (SwipeView) findViewById(R.id.swipe_view);

    mSwipeView.setPageControl(mPageControl);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mSwipeView.addView(new FrameLayout(this));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        ((FrameLayout) mSwipeView.getChildContainer().getChildAt(i))
                .addView(setupView());
        count++;
    }
```

**setupView()**

```
public View setupView() {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout childlayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflator.inflate(
            R.layout.webview, Switcher, false);

            // adding all the things in which define in below XML

    return childlayout;

}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layClick"
                    android:layout_width="43dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/queslay"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    // some stuff

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_question"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/ques"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/option_main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/solution_confirm"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   // some stuff
</LinearLayout>
```

also inflate xml on **"@+id/option_main"** with below xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- <FL><LL><FL></FL><BTN/></LL></FL> -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/option_relative_a"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/option_a"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_a"
                android:layout_width="47dp"
                android:layout_height="19dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/opgrey"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/a"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ch_a"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/cross"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/ques_option_a"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option_image_a"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/option_a"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>


 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/option_relative_b"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/option_b"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_b"
                android:layout_width="47dp"
                android:layout_height="19dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/opgrey"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/b"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ch_b"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/cross"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/ques_option_b"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option_image_b"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/option_b"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/option_relative_c"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/option_c"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_c"
                android:layout_width="47dp"
                android:layout_height="19dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/opgrey"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/c"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ch_c"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/cross"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/ques_option_c"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option_image_c"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/option_c"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/option_relative_d"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/option_d"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_d"
                android:layout_width="47dp"
                android:layout_height="19dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/opgrey"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/d"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ch_d"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/greentick"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/ques_option_d"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option_image_d"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/option_d"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/option_relative_e"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/option_e"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_e"
                android:layout_width="47dp"
                android:layout_height="19dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/opgrey"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/e"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ch_e"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/greentick"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/ques_option_e"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option_image_e"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/option_e"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Swipe working fine but facing problem when going one slide to different slide directly.**

help me if you have also face same kind of problem in past.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This the above problem of flickering so i can read so many link like :-

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20446

[hardware accelerated webview slide-in animation flickering on ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132749/hardware-accelerated-webview-slide-in-animation-flickering-on-ics)

[WebView "flashing" with white background if hardware acceleration is enabled (Android 3.0+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476151/webview-flashing-with-white-background-if-hardware-acceleration-is-enabled-an)

and

**Code**

```
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

above code work for me .

Comment: I use this code and add a 2 seconds delay to show the webview after webview.loadUrl(). And flicker is gone. Thanks!