# Remove white screen in WebView - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview

Upon running the WebView in ICS, I'm encountering such problem, a white screen always flickering before the WebView runs. I don't know if it is normal or not. If yes, are there any other way to remove it? Thanks. Here are my codes.

WebViewSet.java

```
public class WebViewSet {
public static void settings(WebView view) {
    WebSettings s = view.getSettings();
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    s.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    s.setTextZoom(100);
}
}
```

Home.java - Where in my I call my WebView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Layout
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

  // webview
    mWebView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_webview);

    WebViewSet.settings(mWebView);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/blover.swf");

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you still get this problem if you comment out your `WebViewSet.setting(mWebView);` line?

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917191/1638739), The problem of flickering is happened by hardware acceleration, and It can be removed by setting the following :

```
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

also make sure to set the background to transparent:

```
mWebView.setBackgroundResource(Color.Transparent)
```

Comment: The embedded flash never showed. It all turn to black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since this happened because of hardware acceleration. I've searched thoroughly and tried this code. It worked perfectly. If anyone wants to remove the white flickering before it load without disabling hardware acceleration, try this.

webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0));

**NOTE** Make sure you don't have any background that is set in your xml.

Hope it helps anyone.