# Return from WebView Activity goes into black screen on arc welder

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

First of all, thanks in advance to all.

I have researching about an issue with arc welder (testing on Windows 10, chrome version 56.0.2924.87 (Build oficial) (64 bits)) but I am not able to find a solution to this issue.

The problem is when I navigate from a webview activity to come back to any activity of my app, arc welder (not always, but at 80% of times aprox.) shows black screen instead of render activity layout. This issue only can be reproduced on arc welder, because in native devices it works ok.

The webview is used to call google cloud print service, and I finish it's activity when javascript interface "onPostMessage" method is called, because I need to close the activity when print service finishes. (I am using activity example from google developers to manage google cloud print service)

I have tested two options:
- using intents to call activity that I want to navigate to
- using finish() method on webview activity to finish it

I have enabled debug options in arc and I am able to see that activity onResume method is called when I go back from webView activity, but arc shows a black screen.

I have created an issue on chromium bugs in order to get info, but I haven't got an answer at the moment (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=690731)

At this bug I comment about secured http connections issues, but I'm not sure if this is the problem, because sometimes webView activity finishes ok.

I'm also thinking about another possible issue. When I launch webView activity, it seems like arc has issues managing it, because many times webView shows little "blinks" and you can see the latest activity that launch the webView. I mean, when you load webView activity, for example, the webView has the default grey action bar, but it blinks to red color (the launcher activity has a red one). Also, when you are input gmail account to access to print service, you lose keyboard input with some keys (@ key, for example). I suspect that this issue maybe causes the black screen.

If debug info or code is needed I will be pleased to give it.

Thanks all for your attention.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I already solve the issue!
This is related with hardware acceleration... I have research about "blink" effect at webviews and I found this: [web view content flickering in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826997/web-view-content-flickering-in-android)

I have to disable hardware acceleration in webview and it works perfect!

Thanks all for your help! Thanks @Aslam for his response!